# How Can I compare my own sorting algorithm to other ones?

Tags: c++, sorting

I wrote a sorting algorithm and I have implemented it in C++.
How can I compare the speed and performance with other sorting algorithms?
I have the time it takes to sort but I didn't find any resource that have the number of the numbers they tested (in other algorithm) and also the time!

Comment: Try to compute a time complexity bound. There is a theorem which says that it cannot be better than *O(N log N)*. Also, generate a file of many million random integers, and measure the time to sort it (with your program, and with STL library functions).

Comment: First you better know your math behind your algorithm, including average, best, and worst case complexity. Then, [benchmark](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/software-engineering/excerpts/algorithms-in-nutshell/benchmarking.html) them, which is anything-but-trivial if done correctly.

Comment: it worked correct and I have the time but I need the time and the number of numbers they tested from other algorithms to compare it.

Comment: BTW, on which operating system, with which C++ compiler, with which optimization flags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A zip file that includes several sort code examples with timing and results from my system. (The hybrid sort, hsort.cpp consumes a huge amount of memory and is not recommended.). Some of the examples, like msortv.cpp, are converted C programs, that use pointers instead of iterators to sort a vector.

[rsortv.zip](http://rcgldr.net/misc/sortv.zip)

Answer (score 1):

You can start by comparing with std STL sorting algorithm. Also, you can compare with sorted containers, e.g. std::set. It may also be interesting to compare with other languages/OSes - I compared sorting an STL vector on Linux using STL sort to similar code on Windows using .NET and C#, C++ was about twice as fast for a randomized vector.